# Proving that the subspace topology only works for subsets of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

As we already know, the subspace topology is a convenient way to construct topologies from supersets of a set that have a known topology already.

**Subspace Topology**: Suppose you have a set $X$ and a topology on $X$ called $\mathcal{T}_X$. Suppose $Y \subseteq X.$ Then we can find a topology for $Y$, called $\mathcal{T}_Y$, as given by:

$\mathcal{T}_Y=\{O \cap Y  \mid O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$.

I'm going to prove that the induced topology only works for $Y \subseteq X$. Namely, I'm going to prove that the subspace topology fails for $Y \not \subseteq X.$

*Proof*

Suppose $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{T}_X$ is a topology on $X$.

By way of contradiction, let $Y$ be a set such that $Y \not \subseteq X$

Since $Y \not \subseteq X,$ there is at least one $z \in Y$ such that $z \not \in X.$

Let's attempt to construct a topology $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{Y \cap O \mid O \in \mathcal{T}_X\}$

Then for any $O \in \mathcal{T}_X, O \bigcap X \neq Y$. This is because $z \in Y$ but $z$ will never be in $O$ since $O \subseteq X$ and $z \not \in X.$

Then $Y \not \in \mathcal{T}_Y$

This means that $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is not a topology of $Y$ as it violates the definition of topology

Therefore, the subspace topology only works for $Y \subseteq X$ $ \hspace{1cm} \square$

Comment: You have the wrong definition of [induced topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_topology), which is why it only works for $Y\subseteq X$.

Comment: If you're talking about the subspace topology, though, your proof is correct.